# DOMXPath->evaluate not finding the div i need

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, domxpath

Good day all,

I am trying to scrape results and have had success, but i am stuck now.

The code below shows that there is a DIV with a class of 'vsc', and inside that is an H3 with a class of 'r'. I can get the anchor inside of the H3 tag with (//h3[@class='r'//a).

My issue is that the table below that also has an H3 with a class of 'r', and i don't want any of the links inside of the table.

```
<li class="g">
<div class="vsc" pved="0CD4QkgowAA" bved="0CD8QkQo" sig="m15">
<h3 class="r">
<a href="https://ameriloan.com/" class="l" onmousedown="return          rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEazKuyTuAyYgnAT3MqI3aJoiAlZw','','0CDwQFjAA',null,event)">
</h3>
<div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0">
<div class="s">
</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nrgt">
```

Here is the script that I am using to scrape all anchors, but it isn't working to retrieve only the H3 anchor in the 'vsc' DIV:

```
function getURL($url)


{
$ch=curl_init();
// This allows the script to accept HTTPS certificates "blindly"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Follows redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 6);  // follows up to 6 redirects
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
return $ret;
}
$i = 0;
$rawKeyword = 'EXAMPLE';
$keyword = str_replace(' ', '+', $rawKeyword);

$url = "http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=".$keyword;

//get the HTML through cURL function
$html = getURL($url);

// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all data
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// XPath eval to get page links and titles 
//$elementContent = $xpath->evaluate("//h3[@class='r']//a");
$elementContent = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@class='vsc']//h3[@class='r']//a");


// Print results
foreach ($elementContent as $content) {
  $i++;
  $clean = trim($content->getAttribute('href'), "/url?q=");
  echo '<strong>'.$i.'</strong>: <h3 style=" clear:none !important; font-size:10px; letter-spacing:0.1em; line-height:2.6em; text-transform:uppercase;">'.$content->textContent.'</h3><br/>'.$clean.'<br /><br />';
}
```

What am i doing wrong with my evaluate query?

@jdwilemo - 
you are correct in the way Im trying to get only the anchor inside of the DIV with a class of 'vsc'. Here is more of the table code which shows the other H3 DIV with a class of 'r' also...

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="nrgt">
<tbody>
<tr class="mslg">
<td style="vertical-align: top; ">
<div class="sld vsc" pved="0CIYBEJIKMAE" bved="0CIcBEJEK" sig="Q_U">
<span class="tl">
<h3 class="r">
<a href="https://example.com/?page=ent_cs_login" class="l" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNEyANjoolNXGFnLVKH3S1j4CO1qQw','','0CIQBEIwQMAE',null,event)">
</h3>
</span>
<div class="vspib" aria-label="Result details" role="button" tabindex="0">
<div class="s">
</div>
</li>
```

Everything is wrapped in an 'li' tag. The table is the last element in the 'li' tag. I want to get the < H3 class='r'> anchor without getting the < H3 class='r'> anchor inside the table at the end of the 'li' element. I hope i cleared that up...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're wanted only the anchor for an h3 with class=r AND which is under a *div with class=vsc*. But you're getting multiple H3 nodes returned.

If this is correct, you will also need to specify the div's class in your query, as you did with h3: `//div[@class='vsc']/h3[@class='r'//a`

If this isn't the case, then please update your question with further detail and a more expansive xml example which contains the ambiguous data you're referring to and I'll refine my answer, hope this helps!

Just to Note: Using "//" is telling XPath to start from the "root" or beginning, so an XPath of //h3 will return ALL nodes with name = "h3"

**EDIT:**
If you are wanting the anchor that is in the div and NOT within the table element, simply use the  ancestor function like so:

```
//h3[@class='r' and not(ancestor::table)]//a
```

Hope this helps, and let me know if I need to clarify anything else!